# What does a plus sign mean in journal abbreviations?

Tags: journals, citations

On this [journal title abbreviation list](http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOK46/help/WOS/T_abrvjt.html), some abbreviations are followed by a plus sign (+).  For example, "Thermophysics and Aeromechanics" is abbreviated "THERMOPHYS AEROMECH+".

What is the significance of the plus sign, and is it to be included when creating a reference list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Web of science doesn't explain it on the page you quote, but you can find it in another page with detailed explanation: **"The plus sign on this last abbreviation indicates that cites to the original language journal are unified with cites to the translation title"**

From here: http://wokinfo.com/essays/cited-title-unification/

Comment: If that is the case, then I presume the "+" should not be included in the works cited.

Comment: No don't use the + in actual references